# field editor with Matrix

Tags: matrix, field-group, field-editor

I have an EE 2.5.3 build with Field Editor 1.0.3 and Matrix 2.5.2 installed.

When I try to configure the Matrix field from the field list, it looks like it's loading but then craps out.

I get this from the console on load initially

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'rowCallback'
```

and when I click to configure the Matrix field I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MatrixConf is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: Matrix is not defined
```

Works fine when I'm in the default channel fields view and not Field Editor.

Comment: Steven, have you tried updating EE and Matrix to the latest? (2.5.5 and 2.5.3 respectively?)  I see that Field Editor lists Matrix compatibility, so I'd first make sure you're on the latest versions before doing more troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks Lisa, turns out it had nothing to do with Field Editor or Matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the themes path. The site is using MSM and the primary site isn't yet live (DNS points elsewhere at the moment) so we were using the ip address as the theme url.

We copied the themes folder from the primary domain to the secondary domain and we're sweet.